# Usage pattern to read the "latest data" in a CQRS pattern + Event Sourcing

Tags: .net, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am in the process of implementing a test project with CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) pattern.

I have a couple of questions.

1. I want to check the latest price on the data store for an item on a users shopping cart just prior to purchasing. So the real_model (Through a materialized view) price will be checked against the most current price on the data store (product table). I want to show the user an alert if there is a discrepancy between the prices. What is the best way to achieve this?
2. When the User updates their Email and Password should it still rely on creating events to update the DataStore (Event->EventStore->Service Bus->DataStore) or directly update the Data Store? I don't want a delay of the event triggering the read_model_update as the user will have to log back in immediately.

Comment: I understand what I am sacrificing in adopting Eventual Consistency model like Event Sourcing but just want to know whether there are exceptions to the above described scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check the latest price on the data store for an item on a users shopping cart just prior to purchasing... What is the best way to achieve this?

My suspicion is that the "best way to achieve this" is going to depend a lot on the shopping experience that your stakeholders want to deliver to the customer.  IE - when should the price get locked in?  For instance, perhaps the prices shown in the shopping cart are firm quotes with time limits.

But excusing those specifics...

One approach is to run a sanity check against the read model before dispatching the command.  There's a common pattern of (effectively) checking to see if a command would work given the state of the read model, and then dispatching the provisionally verified command to update the book of record.  You trade some latency for a reduced failure rate.

Another possibility would be to use a process manager; the idea being that "placeOrder" isn't a simple write to the model, but rather the beginning of a lifecycle.  So imagine for instance the price quote being a thing in your model -- when an item is placed in the cart, a price quote is generated (perhaps with some expiration value).  When a price changes, all of the different price quotes get updated.  When the order is placed, a handler sees the placedOrder event, and tries to invoke the acceptQuote method on the price quote; if the quote is still valid, then the event generated advances the order process to the next state.  If the quote isn't valid any longer, then either a different event is generated, or the command is rejected and eventually a timeout reveals that there may be a problem....

(You can try doing something similar with the product itself, but that doesn't work so well because of contention problems; the only way to know you are working with *the* most recent state of an object is to have a write to it accepted by the book of record.)

It may be useful to review [Race Conditions Don't Exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) by Udi Dahan.

> When the User updates their Email and Password should it still rely on creating events to update the DataStore (Event->EventStore->Service Bus->DataStore) or directly update the Data Store?

No direct updates -- all updates to the read model should happen-after the update to the book of record.

> I don't want a delay of the event triggering the read_model_update as the user will have to log back in immediately.

The user may log back in immediately, but that doesn't mean you need to acknowledge the login immediately.

For example; via the write model, you've just published a bunch of new events.  Take the sequence number of the highest event you have published, and make that part of the query that gets dispatched to the read model; the login handler checks that sequence number against what is available in the read model, and stalls if the model needs another heartbeat to catch up.

(More likely: in this kind of use case, where you've got a race between the event publishing system and the followup request from the client, you would arrange for a read model that will query the event store as needed.  So your latency is basically going to be a function of the network distance between the read model and the system of record, plus the time required to apply the new events.  In effect, the request from the client serves as an event message indicating that the high water mark has increased, and then the model dispatches a query to fetch the missing history).

Also notice the corollary -- different parts of the read model have different latency requirements.

CQRS is a sort of shell game.  There's still just one system of record, the persistence store that is accepting writes from the model.  That store is optimized for writes.  Read models can be attached to that store (getting the freshest available data, but with extra processing latency because the data is in "write optimized" form), or to projection of that store (where the data is older, but already optimized for the specific read).

Comment: "For example; via the write model, you've just published a bunch of new events. Take the sequence number of the highest event you have published, and make that part of the query that gets dispatched to the read model; the login handler checks that sequence number against what is available in the read model, and stalls if the model needs another heartbeat to catch up."

How much of a delay in practical terms is there between a write and a update occurring in the read model? Is something like 100ms a acceptable use case for 99% of time?

Comment: I tried to flesh out that part of the answer; does it help?

Comment: So the idea is when scaling out scale out so the latency is less? (Latency = Network Latency + other latencies like memory/disk)